# Linked triangle with no field

Tags: ingress

In this image, to the right there is a triangle of 3 portals with all sides linked, but there is no field created:

[image: Map]

How did this happen?  I checked that none of the portals are actually two portals very close together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called null field. It wont disappear.

I am on mobile now, hard to type, later I will edit it.

Here is the explanation:

https://m.reddit.com/r/Ingress/comments/352j0v/empty_fields_how_to_make_them_and_how_to_avoid/

Comment: Cool . That graphic fits with my hypothesis from above... thanks for the response and I look forward to the tidied up post :)

Answer (score 3):

That's a server synchronization problem. It should resolve itself within a day or so. (However, because this is not actually an inconsistent state, it might not.)

Unfortunately, if it's your non-field, you won't get the AP retroactively.

The reason this is not inconsistent: imagine a portal within that triangle. The rule is that the smallest-possible triangle on each side of a link gets the field, thus the link which closed it could have created a field between its endpoints and that inner portal. Now imagine that this inner portal gets deleted or moved for some reason.

Comment: OK. I had another hypothesis too: maybe the blue portal at the left used to be green and connected to the two right-most portals, before the right-most link was put in. Then adding that link would only fill in the larger field; and then the blue portal was captured by blue destroying that field.

Comment: No, ingress doesn't work that way. When a portal changes colors it loses all its links.

Comment: No, the rule is that the largest possible triangle on each side gets the link. And it is linkely not a synchro problem.